# Перезагрузка страницы при отправке формы JS

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, xmlhttprequest

Что нужно исправить, чтобы страница не перезагружалась при отправке формы?

js

```
    let form = new FormData(document.forms.authorForm);
form.addEventListener('submit', addAuthors);
async function addAuthors(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8081/Task1_war_exploded/main?command=addAuthor");
    xhr.send(form);

}
```

jsp

```
 <form name="authorForm">
        <Label>Author (required)</Label>
        <input type="text" id="author" name="author"/>
        <label for="author" ></label>
        <Label>Author image></Label>
        <input type="file" name="authorImage" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg ">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="addAuthor" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: А к чему вы прицепили eventListener?

Comment: к submit, который в форме

Comment: Вы уверены? У вас строчкой выше form это вовсе не форма

Comment: почему не форма, если я обращаюсь к своей форме по названию

Comment: `let form = new FormData(…)` — это не форма (не тег `form`)

Comment: а как можно обратиться к форме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не отправляйте форму в таком виде, используйте javascript. Смотрите, сейчас у вас есть тег `<input>` с `type="submit"`, при его нажатии форма автоматически отправляется, сделайте обычный `div` и уже за его нажатием выполняйте свой `xhr`. В остальном подход у Вас правильный

P.S лучше не отправляйте `form`, а забирайте из неё данные и преобразуйте их в `json`, который в дальнейшем распаковывайте на сервере

Comment: Советовать вместо нормальной формы недоступные div-ы, ну такое…

Comment: Да, вы правы, можно просто изменить `type`, но тогда на какое значение это лучше сделать?

Comment: А ещё лучше сделать просто `button`

Comment: а с помощью чего можно обратиться к форме и забрать из нее данные?

Comment: @mak используйте для этого javascript или Вы имеете ввиду конкретные функции?

Comment: да, я про функции

Comment: @mak самый простой способ "в лоб", присвоить каждому input свой `id` и проходится по ним забирая значения. Но лучшего всего захватить всю форму и вывести в консоль через `console.dir(element)`. Посмотреть все свойства и функции, и попробовать реализовать это через цикл. Но тут готовый код вряд-ли кто-то будет за Вас писать, так что смотрите свойства